# How to bind local storage data to store sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

```
//In view i have created one list with item tpl. below is the code
{
 xtype:'list',
 id:'userReviewList',
 title:'User Review',
 store:'UserReviewStore',
 height:300,
 itemTpl:'<div >{Comment}</div>' + '<div >{Rating}</div>' + '<div >{ReviewId}</div>'
}
```

//Below i am creating model for that  with hard coded values in **data section**.

```
Ext.define('AppName.store.UserReviewStore',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    id:'reviewStore',
    config:{

        fileds:[
            {name:'Comment',type:'string'},
            {name:'Rating', type:'int'},
            {name:'ReviewId',tyep:'int'}
        ]
    },

    data: [
        { Comment: 'nice', Rating: 5, ReviewId: 1 },
        { Comment: 'cool', Rating: 4, ReviewId: 2 },
        { Comment: 'awesome', Rating: 3, ReviewId: 3 }
    ]

})
```

//I am able to display data in list view but i need to use local storage data to display in list. Bellow is the code where i get local storage data which my colleague storing when app starts so now i have to retrieve data from local storage and need to bind to store

```
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');//getting local storage
var jsonObj = Ext.decode(retrievedObject);//decoding
```

after this decode i will get one list of values like

```
var list = jsonObj.userReviewList
```

i need to bind this list to store how to do that . where i should write logic to bind to store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller when your list is activated, shown, or initialized. Some code that can help you to understand what i mean:

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',  
      config: {
        refs: {
          myList: '#userReviewList'
        },
        control: {
          myList: {
            activate: 'onMyListActivate'
          },    
        }  
      },   
      onMyListActivate: function(me) {
        var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');//getting local storage
        var jsonObj = Ext.decode(retrievedObject);//decoding
        var list = jsonObj.userReviewList 
        me.getStore().setData(list);   
      }
  });
```

Comment: control not going inside that method ..can u suggest me how to write a code in show method that i can access list and bind local storage data to list.

Comment: //instead on writing code to activate method i have written in show method that works  fine buddy thank u Dmytro

    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');
    var jsonObj = Ext.decode(retrievedObject);
    this.getUserReviewList().getStore().setData(jsonObj.UserRatings);